# Samsung Galaxy Tab layout in graphical layout xml

Tags: android, eclipse, galaxy

Can anybody help me set the graphical layout option in eclipse to the dimensions of the Galaxy tab (1024 x 600). I have the emulator set up perfectly its just designing the layout of everything using the .xml and the graphical layout version.

I find it helps me visualize it better when what I design is what I see in the emulator. At the moment my only solution is trial and error.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is very difficult to understand what you want based on your question. Do you need to setup the emulator or figure out how to write layout for galaxy tab?

Comment: In eclipse when you open an xml file in the layout resources you can either view this in text based xml form or "Graphical Layout" which is a black box where you can drag and drop different Views to build up the UI of an application, I need to be able to change this black box to the size ratio of the Galaxy Tab. I have tried with a custom one but it didn't work and was wondering if anybody knew the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a bigger view in the 'Layout Design' tab by clicking on the clipping button(next to the outline button) in the upper right hand corner.  This will not perhaps get you the exact layout dimensions but it will give you more space.

Comment: Clicking that did nothing to my layout at all.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung offers a third party addon. You can download it if interested.

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do

To increase the layout height and width select custom from the Graphical layout view and create a new size for landscape and portrait mode.